# Can a Razor view have more than one model without using a ViewModel object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@model MyMVC.Models.MyMVC.MyModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

The reason why I ask this question is in MVC we can have more than 1 form, so I would like to have a model for each form. But when I was trying to add another model at the top of the view, it displays an error.
I know we can use **ViewModel** which has model1 and model2 inside, but it's not the question I am asking.

I just simply want to know is there any way that we can put in 2 models into 1 view.

**Update:**

For example, I want to have 2 forms in my view, so for each form I'd like to have a separated model.

**Update 2**
Thank you all for your replies. I now know that MVC only supports one single model on one view. Do you guys consider this a disadvantage of MVC? Why or Why not?(No one has answered it yet.... why?)

Your answers are similar, so I don't even know which one should be set as an answer.

Comment: While each View can only have one Model, you can have PartialViews within a View.  Each PartialView can have its own model.  In your example, each form would be its own PartialView.

Comment: @drovani thx for your reply. Could you express your idea with code please?

Comment: Consider using @Html.Partial() instead of the suggestion in accepted answer. There may be an issue with @Html.RenderAction, since it will look for a controller route and then render the 'partial' as a complete view. This will probably load the _Layout.cshtml twice in your page!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use some prtialviews for other models. You have your main view with main model. Inside of that view, you could have some partialviews with their models and their validations.

--------------------------------------Edit:

As others said it is better to use View Models and combine the models with each others. But as you wanted I created a sample project for you on my Github account:

https://github.com/bahman616/ASPNET_MVC_multiple_models_in_a_view_with_partialview.git

Here is the simplified code of that project:

Here are two models:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public partial class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have both create views in one view, so this is the parent view:

```
@model ASP_NET_MVC_Multiple_Models_In_A_View.Models.Person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Person")) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Person</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@{Html.RenderAction("_CompanyCreate", "Company");}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And this is the partial view:

```
@model ASP_NET_MVC_Multiple_Models_In_A_View.Models.Company

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("_CompanyCreate","Company")) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Company</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: You are quite welcome Franva, I'm here if you have any other questions. If you want to use two or three models in a view it is better to use view model. Anyway I'm happy to help you because I am moving to Melbourne next month :D

Answer (score 6):

**Simple answer:**
No, you can't have two models.

**Details**
There is only one way to declare a Model to be used by a view:

```
@model [namespace].[path].[ViewModelName]
```

There is no way to specify multiple of these above.

In addition to that, you can only send one object to a view from the Controller, which would be the model:

```
public ActionResult WhateverAction()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Theoretically you cant do it because it binds one model to one view. But you can create somethink like a model helper which combines two other models to one

```
public class model1
{
     string var1 {get; set;}
     string var2 {get; set;}
}

public class model2
{
     string var3 {get; set;}
     string var4 {get; set;}
}

public class modelofBoth
{
     model1 mod1 {get; set;}
     model2 mod2 {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: THx Code Told :) It is an viable way, like the ViewModel classes in MVVM design pattern

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot/don't want to modify the model passed to the view then you could pass the additional object in via the ViewBag object.  It feels like a hack to me but it works:

Controller:

```
ViewBag["Model2"] = yourObject
```

View:

```
@{var Model2 = ViewBag["Model2"] as yourObjectType;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you could write your own view engine (derived from the RazorViewEngine?) using a custom WebViewPage and have it do whatever you want. The view derives from `WebViewPage<T>` where `T` is the type of the model for the page.  To support multiple models, the view base class would need to have multiple generic types. Using the baked in RazorViewEngine, however, you're limited to a single model type per view and much of the controller framework presumes a single model per view so you'd have to rewrite that, too. There doesn't seem to be much point in that, however, as you could simply have your models be properties of the (single) view model, then use partial views for each of the forms providing the property as the model for the partial.

For more information see http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Answer is NO. Thats why ViewModel pattern Exists. because the razor engine is totally relied on the model you passed, the model is used for ModelBinding for the basic CRUD Operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily have 1 model per form. For each form, you just have to do something like this:

```
var model = new MyModel();
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => model.Title)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => model.Title)
```

The validation works like a charm.

This way, you can keep your model to display information as usual and have 1 model per form to submit data (for example newsletter subscription)

Answer (score 0):

if your models are similar,
Make a new model contains references to all models you want, and use it.
if models are not similar, you can fill new model with similar fields you need from all your models.
but if you wants use totally different models, you should use **Partial view**s.