# How to use ValidationMessageFor when there are 2 models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

When we have multiple models one for loading page and another for the form within that page, and i have a form model property validation. I cannot use page model as it does not contain form property and form property is not accessible for @Html.ValidationMessageFor. How to use ValidationMessageFor when there are 2 models?

Comment: refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14516259/9804714)

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for you
https://github.com/bahman616/ASPNET_MVC_multiple_models_in_a_view_with_partialview.git.
I think you can't have two models.there is only one way to declare a Model to be used by a view but there will be another way like model helper which combines two other models to one. It may be possible but I don't have any idea.e.g.

```
 @model ASP_NET_MVC_Multiple_Models_In_A_View.Models.Employee-
 /@model/namespace/path/ViewModelName.
```